# Spotfire 6.5 is not handling complex DataTables joins correctly

Tags: spotfire

Inside company I'm working at we're using Spotfire to develop templates for our Customers for their internal reporting. One of such templates has a pretty bad and complex hierarchies & relations which we believe Spotfire is not handling correctly (or we're doing something wrong). To give a little background how things work:

We have DataTable1 which has relative way of providing hierarchies of certain Product, structure and values looks like this:
[image: 1]
To data from DatTable1 we want to join data from DataTable 3 which has absolute hierarchies as below:
[image: 2]]

and show data from both DataTables in one CrossTable.

Additionally, as DT1 is being load earlier than DT3, we're using DT1 to limit DT3 using Column values. To do that properly we need to use another DataTable (DT2) which contains straight information about Product from Level 0 to Level 6 as below:

[image]

Filtering inside DT3 is driven by IronPython script which is used to populate information to Spotfire properties which DataTable and Column should be used to limit data inside DT3. Process is explained below:
[image: 3]]

For higher level of hierarchies this works perfectly, but at some point (for Hier_lvl 3 and below) Spotfire is displaying following error

"Column "DT1.PROD_0" refers to a non existing table".
We tripled checked - DT1 exists, Column exists. Spotfire is still not seeing it. 
Any idea what might be an issue here? is this Spotfire bug or we're handling something incorrectly?

Regarding IronPython script: that's how it basically looks [ignore syntax, wrote it fast while being home, might contain mistakes, it's supposed to give a general idea how this is working]
http://pastebin.com/NE6ktheh

We have a property which sets Hierarchy Level which is required by DT1 and DT3 and DTPROD_X properties which are later on placed as a limitation for DT3.

Comment: This is tough. The schema is SUPER confusing and can probably be simplified but it's hard to understand. The error could be in the IronPy script, it could be in the Table Relations, it's just hard to tell. Can you explain the point of the hierarchy table(s)?

Comment: Well, basically each Product has some attributes like Category, Brand, Item Number, yada yada, and out of those we're making hierarchies. Thing is that certain ex. Brand can exists within let's say 2 Categories (so let's say value from PROD_2 can exists for two different PROD_1 values), but User wants to see the data for certain PROD_2, so to do that correctly we need to have those relatives hierarchies. Basically in thing above DT1 and DT3 contains some extra data, while DT2 is just hierarchy table which is helpful in some Treemaps + used for this complex join. Hope it clarifies a bit

Comment: Can you provide the IropPy script? I'm loading this into test to see if I can resolve it. Also seeing what is in DataTable (DT2) would be awesome.

Comment: @scsimon done. let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Still looking at this but it's hard to wrap my head around.